# Different views when nesting resources in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, nested-resources

I am using Rails 3.2.1.

Is it possible to use different views when using nested resources? i.e. profile/comments post/comments. Let's say you want both pages to look completely different. Is there a way to do this without overriding render in every controller action?

Preferably I still want to use respond_with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't find anything, and in the end I did it the following way:

```
class NestedController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :retrieve_parent
  before_filter :retrieve_scope

  layout :retrieve_layout

  def retrieve_scope
    @scope = @parent.nil? ? controller_name : @parent.class.name.pluralize.downcase || ''
  end

  def retrieve_view
    controller_name + '/' + @scope + '/' + action_name
  end

  def retrieve_parent
    params.each do |name, value|
      if name =~ /(.+)_id$/
        @parent = $1.classify.constantize.find(value)
      end
    end
  end

  def retrieve_layout
   template_exists?(@scope, 'layouts') ? @scope : 'application'
  end

end
```

Every controller that uses nested resources, will extend from NestedController.

Note that the retrieve_parent function has been derived from Ryan's railscast about polymorphic associations.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and what I did was first split up controllers, as in:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14947230/1641163

and then I provided a separate view for each nested controller. When you run `rails generate controller Profile_Comments new create index` you get the corresponding views and helpers in the right directories (or you can of course just create them and put them there manually), and those are the views that will be rendered by default.