# What is the right way to handle belongs_to relationships in Rails controllers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, design-patterns

Say, for example, that I have 2 resources `Author` and `Book`, where  `Author has_many Books` and `Book belongs_to Author`.

This means that by doing the following:

```
# routes.rb

resources :books
resources :authors do
  resources :books
end
```

I will have two routes that point to `BooksController#index`:
1) `GET /books` and 2) `GET /authors/:id/books`.

Consider the scenario where we don't care about all the books, only 
the list of books from a given author (effectively putting route #1 out of use).

This leaves `BooksController#index` with logic that goes something like:

```
# BooksController.rb

def index
  @books = Book.where(author: author)
  render json: @books
end
```

However, the `Author` scoping is leaving me quite uncomfortable seeing as it is a general `BooksController`, where the other CRUD methods have nothing to do with `Authors`. **Should something like the above #index method be in a separate, namespaced controller like `Author::BooksController`?**

Comment: refer this question. might help you :)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14945754/rails-nested-resources-and-routing-how-to-break-up-controllers

Answer (score 2):

I would just pass an `author_id` to `books#index` to filter the books by a specific author.

Then `books#index` would like this:

```
def index
  @books = Book.all
  @books = @books.where(author_id: params[:author_id]) if params[:author_id]
  render json: @books
end
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense and is a typical way to handle this scenario. It also keeps things simpler as you don't need additional nested routes, just the main `/books` route that reads `?author_id` param. In case there's a lot of filter params, like `author, publish_year, genre` I usually map those directly to AR scopes with something like: https://github.com/plataformatec/has_scope